# Reading multiple netcdf files

Tags: r, netcdf, ncdf4

I am trying to read multple nc4 files in r. below is the code I am using to execute this task;

```
library(ncdf4)
OSND_gpmr.df<-NULL

GPM_R.files= list.files(path,pattern='*.nc4',full.names=TRUE) 

for(i in seq_along(GPM_R.files)) {
  nc_data = nc_open(GPM_R.files[i])

  GPM_Prec<-ncvar_get(nc_data, 'IRprecipitation')

  x=dim(GPM_Prec)

  ### note start=c(42,28) are the index in image regards to real coordinates of interset
  ## R reads images from lat,long. 
  OSND_gpmr.spec =ncvar_get(nc_data, 'IRprecipitation', start = c(42,28), count = c(1,1))
  rbind(OSND_gpmr.df,data.frame(OSND_gpmr.spec))->OSND_gpmr.df 

  nc_close(nc_data)
}
```

but I consistently get this error:

> Error in R_nc4_open: No such file or directory.

But the list of files is correctly recognised as chr [1:1440] as shown in the global environments-Values.

Can someone please help me with what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your working directory might have been different from the files location. Your GPM_R.files list stores only the file names from the given location without file paths. While nc_open() expects filenames with complete path.